# how to pass sql commands from Java

Tags: java, sql, jakarta-ee, setstring

I am trying to pass a SQL command where a row has to be deleted from the database.
I m using setString(index, value) and invoking the method in the main class. But when I pass the parameter to the method in the main class nothing happens in the database. Is there a form to pass the value of "jobnumber=?" in the main method so it deletes that row from the database?
Ps: jobnumber is declared as serial and is the primary key in the database.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DeleteUserDao {
    Connection conDB2 = Connect.connectDB();    
    public void deleteDb(String y) {
        String sqlDelete = ("DELETE FROM bookings WHERE jobnumber=?");      
        try {
            PreparedStatement deleter = conDB2.prepareStatement(sqlDelete);
            deleter.setString(1, y);            
            System.out.println("Item deleted from Bookings.");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Coud not delete item. " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

import ***.jdbc.DeleteUserDao;

public class DeleteTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DeleteUserDao del = new DeleteUserDao();        
        del.deleteDb("4");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, you're missing [`executeUpdate()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate%28%29) for the `Statement`,

```
PreparedStatement deleter = conDB2.prepareStatement(sqlDelete);
deleter.setString(1, y);
deleter.executeUpdate(); // <-- like so
```

From the linked Javadoc,

> Executes the SQL statement in this PreparedStatement object, which must be an SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statement, such as INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE; or an SQL statement that returns nothing, such as a DDL statement.

**Edit**

As noted in the comments below, you should probably be using an `int` type and you need to close your `PreparedStatement` -

```
public void deleteDb(int y) {
  String sqlDelete = ("DELETE FROM bookings WHERE jobnumber=?");     
  PreparedStatement deleter = null; 
  try {
    deleter = conDB2.prepareStatement(sqlDelete);
    deleter.setInt(1, y);            
    System.out.println("Item deleted from Bookings.");
  } catch (SQLException e) {
    System.out.println("Coud not delete item. " + e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
  } finally {
    if (deleter != null) {
      try {
        deleter.close();
      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then to call it, pass it an `int` -

```
del.deleteDb(4);
```

Comment: Imho `setString` won't work for an `integer` field http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/datatype.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL

Comment: to cite the author:  **jobnumber is declared as serial and is the primary key in the database** `deleter.setString(1, y);` should be `deleter.setInt(1, y);`

Comment: Why `executeUpdate()` and not normal `execute()
`?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't actually told the program to run the command.

In the `prepareStatement` call, you told the program "This is the format of the command I'll run, and I may run it multiple times with different parameters in place of the question marks", and in the `setString` call you said "At the moment, I think I'll want to run the command with parameter 1 set to the value of y", but you never actually said "execute the statement". Which you'd do by running:

```
deleter.execute();
```

The reasons for this are manifold, but the most facile example would be if you were running a prepared statement with two parameters, and you planned on running that statement 400 times.

Say you had `"DELETE FROM bookings WHERE jobnumber=? AND personid=?"`, and you ran:

```
deleter.setString(1, y);
deleter.setString(2, y);
```

Then, you wanted to set parameter 1 to some value x, and parameter 2 to some value z. So you run:

```
deleter.setString(1, x);
deleter.setString(2, z);
```

If things worked the way you assumed in your question, this would have unexpected behavior, because parameters 1 and 2 are already both set to `y`, so setting parameter 1 to x would make parameter 1 become x and 2 remain y, and both parameters would be set which would prompt an automatic execute of the SQL on both those calls to `setString`. Which wouldn't be what you'd want.

On the other hand, if you *did* just want to change parameter 1, and didn't want to change parameter 2, it would be more convenient to simply be able to say:

```
deleter.setString(1, x);
deleter.execute();
```

Instead of:

```
deleter.setString(1, x);
deleter.setString(2, y);
```

In that particular example, it doesn't save much effort. But if you had a prepared statement with 30 parameters, and between each successive call you only change 1 or 2 of them on average, this paradigm saves enormous effort.